# Excel on Mac. Cannot open IQY file in Data/Get External Data/Run Web Query

Tags: excel-web-query

I am running Excel version 16.45 on Mac.
I have created a .iqy and saved it in the Queries directory alongside certain templates which were already there.
I go to Data/Get External Data/Run Web Queries. While the templates are accessible, my file is visible but greyed out (same thing happens if I save the file in a different directory).

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: maybe if you shared some caption of your problem we could help you better it is not clear what you described, maybe you should take captions of the steps you do to open your .iqy

Answer (score 0):

According to your information, I would like to confirm whether the issue occurs when you follow the steps as below:

1.Create a Word file, paste the web URL.

2.Save the Word as .iqy with .txt format.

3.Choose MS-DOS as coding.

4.Create an Excel file and click "Data >Get External Data >Run Web Query (Or Run Saved Query) " of the Bar

Comment: Hi, the above is exactly what I have done. When I get to Step 4, I can see the directory where the file is stored but the file is greyed out.

Comment: share at least the properties of the file !

Comment: It is a very simple file. Contains a single URL. Created as per your instructions above, with Microsoft Word, formatted as plain text, renamed .iqy, MS-DOS.

Comment: sorry I can't help you like that

Answer (score 0):

I was able to address the issue as follows.

When navigating to the relevant directory with Finder, the '.iqy' file appears to be appropriately named (as per Image 1).

In fact, if you reach the file in Terminal, the file is saved as '.iqy.txt'.

So all I had to do is rename the file, simply removing the '.txt' string at the end.

[Screen you see when navigating in Finder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbEZ9.png)